# What is the meaning of "otherwise" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> It seems that corporations have no choice but to create an infrastructure which otherwise would be public. The world is becoming a "company town".

That's a comment I read on an article on futurism website. What is the meaning of "otherwise" in this context?
https://www.facebook.com/futurism/posts/859206647591869

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/otherwise

Comment: @AhmadMoustafa: It is not appropriate to ask editors, commenters, close-voters, etc to answer your questions. If they have anything else helpful to contribute, they'll generally do so without you bothering them, and anything they already did is already more than they had to, more than you can expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

otherwise = alternatively; if not done, then

If the companies did not create the infrastructure, then the need for infrastructure would result in the public sector (government) creating it.